# Applying for Canadian visa, should I mention UK visa I had previously?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, applications

I went to the UK to study after 12th? But I left College and I came back to India before my visa expired. I continued my study in India and started working. I want to apply for Canada now but I don't want to mention about the UK Visit as it will affect my application. What can happen? My passport is clean as I lost the last one which had my UK visa in.

Comment: `but i dont want to mention about UK Visit as it will affect my application` Why ? Did you commit crime ? If you hide the UK visa, you willn't get the Canadian visa too and maybe barred from other countries too as you are lying.

Comment: Deception is far worse than any thing in your past that you might think will not look good for you.Tell the truth, but only answer the questions you are actually asked.

Comment: You should provide correct information. Canada will probably see it as a *positive* that you got a UK visa, traveled there, and left before it expired. And if they find out you lied, they can restrict you from getting a visa for life. Why do you want to hide this?

Comment: `I went to UK to study after 12th....` what does this mean? 12th of what?

Comment: I think you should mention it. But now you should stay at home, as countries stop all international travel on a daily bases, sometimes restrict local travel, or do some other measure because of the pandemic. You don't want to be stuck in a hotel room in Canada, right?

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Most likely Class 12, the [final year of high school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelfth_grade#India).

Answer (score 14):

You must answer all questions truthfully. Australia, Canada, New Zealand, UK and USA share immigration data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes; while the extent to which they do this is unknown, you should assume that Canada will know, or can easily find out, about your previous UK visa. Having a ‘clean’ passport makes no difference - your visa history can be traced via biometrics, for example.

You don’t say why you don’t want to disclose your UK visa, from which it seems reasonable to assume you have something to hide. If you tell the truth, there’s a chance it may not affect your application. If you lie, there’s a good chance it’ll be discovered, and your application will be refused. You’ll then have a black mark on your immigration history that will be difficult to overcome, plus a possible ban for deception. If you think whatever it is you’re trying to hide is sufficiently serious to warrant lying in a visa application - don’t apply.

Comment: The OP never said anything about lying.  But every piece of data will have a positive or negative impact; the OP just wants to know if including information on the previous UK visit will help or hurt his application.

Comment: @Jennifer “I dont want to mention...” rather difficult to interpret that another way, if the visa application asks for it.

Comment: @Jennifer Do visa applications ever have optional questions? Either they ask for it and you should provide the information, or they don't and you shouldn't. This answer may be missing what you should do if they don't ask for it. In a more open-ended visa interview or motivation letter, it may be slightly different (but you should still answer everything truthfully).

Answer (score 7):

> I want to apply for Canada now but I don't want to mention about the
>   UK Visit as it will affect my application.

Does the visa application give you a "tell the truth" option and a "tell a lie" option?

If there is no such option given, the immigration officers expect that you are telling the truth. If they catch you lying you will likely never be able to travel to that country in your entire life.

Comment: The OP never said anything about lying.  But every piece of data will have a positive or negative impact; the OP just wants to know if including information on the previous UK visit will help or hurt his application.

Comment: @Jennifer I appreciate that. They did suggest that they want to withhold information: "I continued my study in India and started working. I want to apply for Canada now but I don't want to mention about the UK Visit as it will affect my application." We will need more information from OP about why he doesn't want to mention the UK visit. Is it because the visa application doesn't ask for it, and people who have travelled a lot are less likely to get a visa? Or is it because there's something he wants to hide. Let's see what the OP says. For now I just wrote a "careful" answer.